# when I insert letterin VBA, it takes time between 2 letters like 2 seconds

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks to help me.

when I insert letter, it takes time between 2 letters like 2 seconds.

[image]

I insert these letter in excel to list them.

[image]

```
Private Sub Num_Article_Info_Generale_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données Enregistrées").Activate


Range("A$2").Value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text


End Sub
```

Is there an possibility to delete these 2 seconds waiting when we are writing thes letters??

Many thanks

Comment: How does `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données Enregistrées").Range("A2").Value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text` fair? This will stop the activation of the sheet before changing the value.

Comment: Are there a lot of formulas pointing at the cell that is being modified?

Comment: Dear,No there is just one formul pointing the cell. thanks